# tooltip on a dropdown list

Tags: drop-down-menu, tooltip

Is there anyway of showing a tooltip on the dropdown list?
such as when the list is dropped and a person hovers over each option a tooltip or something with details appears. this is for a drop down list with a cascading drop down.

this is for asp.net

Comment: It rather depends what platform you're talking about. And, unless you're clients are followers Maharishi Mahesh Yogi, your users won't be hovering.

Comment: Why you say so? Curious to know about this Maharishi Mahesh Yogi followers.

Answer (score 3):

Marco, not sure what browser your demographic is, but the standard code below works for FF.

```
<select>
<option value="1" title="this is text about the value">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in code behind (c#):

```
        foreach (Widget w in Widgets)
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem(w.Name, w.WidgetID.ToString());
            item.Attributes.Add("title", w.TooltipText);

            ddlWidgets.Items.Add(item);
        }
```